# Why does this 9-patch image look bad on my Galaxy 3 tablet?

Tags: android, resolution, nine-patch

Why does this 9-patch image look bad on my Galaxy 3 tablet after creating resolution folders and generating the various resolutions for this file? Am I creating the 9-patch incorrectly? The dropdown looks fine below, but on the screen it is super-tiny.

UPDATE: I included the wrong file at first. This has now been corrected. I am using a .9.png extension.

Code in main "styles.xml" file:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/spinnerStyle</item>
 </style>

<style name="spinnerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/icon_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: 9 patch spinner]

Comment: Try to use only one black element at left side (like here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Comment: @Danil Onyanov: That won't help. The black arrow will be then moved to the lower or to the upper part of the dropdown, instead of being centered. The picture you are referring is at the "mid point" of a gradient and it has no "icon" to take in account.

Comment: Sorry...I updated the picture; I uploaded the wrong one.

Comment: @Artoo Detoo I am using a .9.png extention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by lowering the input resolution size on the application that I was using to generate the different resolutions.